# Best place to hook Prestashop and check remote product availibility

Tags: php, module, prestashop

I created a module that adds products from a remote resource but I want to check the price and availibility of a product before this is displayed in the browser.

I tried to change it in Bootstrap module:

```
<?php

public function hookHeader($params)
{
    $controller = $this->context->controller;

    if(!($controller instanceof ProductController)) {
        return;
    };

    /* @var $controller ProductController */
    $product = $controller->getProduct();

    $product->name = 'Test Name';
    $product->price = 20;
    $product->quantity = 5;
    $product->update();
}
```

But the old values are already in the templates.

Then I tried to override ProductController:

```
<?php

public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    $product = $this->product;
    /* @var $product Product */

    $product->price = 10;
    $product->quantity = 10;
    $product->update();
}
```

But happens the same that the first example.

So the questions are:

1. Where is the best place to check remote data and update the product before it is drawn on the output?
2. Best method to update price and quantity? Directly to the class or using StockAvailableCore class?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best way to way to update your product data is in your module hook function, and with StockAvailable class.